# Convert 12,34 into 12.34 in Django template for css purposes

Tags: css, django, templates

I have to deal with django, so here goes my question. I have a template where I want to calculate values and then use them in css. It looks like:

```
padding-top: {{ VAL1|divide:VAL2|multiply:VAL3 }}px
```

It calculates the value I need albeit in some strange fashion via filters, I am ok with that since I am already dealing with django :( The problem is that the result of calculation has comma inside like `12,34` whereas `12.34` is needed for css to work properly - `padding-top: 12,34px` isn't valid css due to the comma (I use google chrome). I tried to use `floatformat` filter - no success. It looks like a simple thing but I cannot wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After delving into django docs I learnt that the described effect may occur due to the localization, so I added the following in the template:

```
{% load l10n %} # at the beginning
...
{{ VAL1|divide:VAL2|multiply:VAL3|unlocalize }} # to output without localization
```

Seems it helped, although I don't mind if someone savvy brings another solution.